# SQL Where != stringval not filtering out stringval

Tags: sql

I have a table (as **table1**)comes from HBase that has certain things that I would like to filter out. I have recreated the table, my SQL query, and the output I receive below. What happens is that when I try to filter out the string value it stays in the table, even if I want it out.

**table1** ( some positions are fully capitalized some arent, want to make them all capitalized and filter out positions )

```
name | company  | personal_id | position
Joe  | Applebees| 32          | manager
Jack | Target   | 12          | CLERK
Jim  | Chipotle | 22          | COOK
Ron  | Starbucks| 13          | barista
```

**query**

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select name, company, personal_id, UCASE(position) as position
                     from table1
                     where position != 'BARISTA'") #tried lower & upper case
```

**Output Reieved**

```
name | company  | personal_id | position
Joe  | Applebees| 32          | MANAGER
Jack | Target   | 12          | CLERK
Jim  | Chipotle | 22          | COOK
Ron  | Starbucks| 13          | BARISTA  /*dont want this output*/
```

Why did the row `Ron | Startbucks| 13 | BARISTA` not filter with my where clause?

Comment: try **<>** insted of **!=**

Comment: It's possible that there is whitespace after "barista" in the `position` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
where UCASE(position) != 'BARISTA'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you grouping the result. there is no need to group the result until aggregate function is used. Try below query -

```
select name, company, personal_id, UCASE(position) as position
from table1
where upper(position) != 'BARISTA'
```

Comment: doing a counter in the future, took it out.